# In Kotlin, how to define a property of a generic type with a upper bound limit?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, generics

What is the Kotlin equivalent of the following Java code?

```
class Test {
    Class<? extends Number> types = new Class[] {
            Integer.class, Long.class, Short.class, Byte.class, Float.class, Double.class
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `out` keyword:

```
var types: Array<Class<out Number>> = arrayOf(
    Integer::class.java, 
    Long::class.java, 
    Short::class.java, 
    Byte::class.java, 
    Float::class.java, 
    Double::class.java
)
```

`out` modifier is used to indicate **covariance** (similar to `? extends T` in Java). **Covariance** - is the ability to change the generic type argument from a class to one of its parents, i.e. assign `List<String>` to `List<Any>`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is a covariant array, or `out` variance on your generic parameter:

```
var types: Array<Class<out Number>> = arrayOf(
        Int::class.java,
        Long::class.java,
        Short::class.java,
        Byte::class.java,
        Float::class.java,
        Double::class.java
)
```

This sort of thing is covered in the documentation under [variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) (although it might take a while to untangle it all, if you're new to it).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you could produce the same code in Kotlin using Kotlin data types as;

```
var types: Array<KClass<out Number>> = arrayOf(
        Int::class,
        Long::class,
        Short::class,
        Byte::class,
        Float::class,
        Double::class
    )
```

Here we use `KClass` which is the Kotlin class reference type and `out` is covariance type annotation (producer).